# xilinx sdka error when using lwip library

Tags: fpga, lwip, microblaze, xilinx-edk

I'm trying to create an echo server on spartan 3 A  with MicroBlaze using ethernet interface, but when i compile the project i got an undefined reference error. I am   using lwip 1.3.0.

I think that i am missing a library but I can't get which one?

The error is:

> microblaze_0\libsrc\lwip130_v3_01_a\src/contrib/ports/xilinx/sys_arch.c:347 >undefined reference to `sem_post'

Comment: If you note the link to the possible duplicate question the source code there has the reference `#include <semaphore.h>`.  `[sem_post](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ "sem_post") is a call that requires that reference. (the call is iin libc, the declaration for the function is found through the include file).

Comment: i included already <semaphore.h> and linked the library lib c, my problems was that in xilkernel configuration there was an option to activate threads and semaphore and now it is working, thanks